# How to save a NSHashTable to file?

Tags: objective-c, hashtable, save

I would like to save my NSHashTable to a plist file. I understand that there is a way to do this with NSMutableArrays, but will that method or a similar method work for NSHashTables?

```
array writeToFile:path atomically:YES
```

This is what I would try to do for an array, does this also work for NSHashTables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NSHashTable class conforms to the NSCoding protocol, so you can easily store it to disk using the encodeWithCoder method. ( See NSCoding protocol for details )

You would use something like this :
    [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:dict toFile:filePath];

where dict is an NSDictionary with a key of your choice and the object as value for that key.

Hope that helps,

best,

Flo